# Astropy transform_to ignoring equinox

Tags: python, astropy

I want to convert coordinates from B1950 to J2000, but it appears that the new equinox is being ignored while using transform_to:

```
c = PrecessedGeocentric(x=x*u.au, y=y*u.au, z=z*u.au, equinox=Time('B1950.0'),
             obstime=Time('J1999.0'), representation_type='cartesian')
```

then after calling transform to this way:

```
f = c.transform_to(PrecessedGeocentric(equinox=Time('J2000.0'), representation_type='cartesian'))
```

and inspecting f it appears that the new equinox has been ignored.

```
<PrecessedGeocentric Coordinate (equinox=B1950.000, obstime=J1999.000, obsgeoloc=(0., 0., 0.) m, obsgeovel=(0., 0., 0.) m / s): (x, y, z) in AU
    (0.7480194, 0.58555774, 0.25393959)>
```

I suspected that it may not work since J2000 is the default value, but it also doesn't change when converting from J2000 to B1950.

I am using the newest astropy (4.2 at the moment), has anybody had a similiar problem, perhaps, or am I making a mistake here?

Comment: I'm not a coordinates expert, but I think this might be a buglet, as there is no self-transform registered for transforming a `PrecessedGeocentric` frame to another `PrecessedGeocentric` frame with different equinox (e.g. such a transform is explicitly defined for `FK5`, but not in this case).